# Recursive flood fill function triggering stack overflow error (sometimes)

Tags: javascript, html, stack-overflow, flood-fill

As an exercise, I have implemented a simple pixel editor. One of the modes is flood fill which utilizes a recursive solution. It works without issue on grid sizes of less than approximately 40x40 pixels. When testing it on larger grid sizes however (such as 64x64) only part of the board will be covered an console will show an error `Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded`. This, of course, indicates that the hard-coded call stack size for the given browser has been exceeded. For Chrome there is a problem for 64x64. For Firefox there is not.

I am surprised that what I thought was a straightforward implementation of flood fill is leading to an error like this making me think that I have done something wrong. Adding to the confusion is the fact that the error is not generated consistently in Chrome. Let me explain-- when I first open the webpage containing my app and attempt the flood fill, the error is generated always. When I clear the board (setting all div cells to 'white') and attempt the flood fill function again the board usually fills completely just fine.

While working the problem I also included a counter variable inside of the floodFill function with increments by one each time the function is called. For the first run (which leads to a failure) it acheives a value of around 4000. After clearing the board and attempting again it reaches around 16,000 and the board is completely filled. This seems to dispell any notion that something about the way I am clearing the board reduces the depth of the recursion.

So... 1) Any idea what is happening here? and 2) Have I done a poor job of writing my algorithm?

Assuming that I have either made a mistake with my algorithm, I would still like to know the answer to 1). Why are the results seemingly non-deterministic.

```
 function floodFill(xCoordinate, yCoordinate, fillColor, regionColor) {

    //checks to make sure that there is a cell at the specified coordinate
    if(!(row[yCoordinate] && row[yCoordinate][xCoordinate])) {
        return
    }   
    //checks if cell is already filled with the appropriate color
    else if(row[yCoordinate][xCoordinate].style.backgroundColor === fillColor) {
        return
    }
    //checks to see if this cell is apart of the region that is SUPPOSED to be colored
    else if(row[yCoordinate][xCoordinate].style.backgroundColor !== regionColor) {
        console.log("nope: not fill region");
        return
    }

    //changes the color of the current cell if the above conditions don't triger a return
    brush.prototype.changeCellColor(xCoordinate, yCoordinate);

    //creates a variable storing the displacment vectors that specify which cells to check next
    var coordinates = [
        [0, -1],
        [1, 0],
        [0, 1],
        [-1, 0]
    ];

    // recursivley runs the floodFill function of each of the cells specified by the displacement vectors
    coordinates.forEach(function(element){
        floodFill(xCoordinate + element[0], yCoordinate + element[1], fillColor, regionColor);
    });
}
```

Comment: Why do you think it's non-deterministic?  You say the behavior changes *when you change the starting state* which sounds deterministic to me.  For debugging you could pass a nesting level variable and alert / break when it exceeds some depth.  You're probably reaching an edge case where the same step(s) repeat endlessly.

Comment: Metaphysically I don't think it is non-deterministic of course. But the result of repeating the same action (flood fill) does seem to depend on hidden variables beyond the states specified in my code-- if the divs are all white and I haven't tried to fill them before the error appears at a counter much less then if I *have* run it before. Additionally, even if I have run it before the algorithm does not always seem to run without error-- even if I click on the same cell on the blank grid. I will try the nesting level variable suggestion although I am confused because the same code works in FF.